# Camel in action source code import in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-camel, m2eclipse, m2e

I downloaded [source code](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction) and 'Import | Maven | Existing Maven Project' into Eclipse Kepler. I have maven setup right, as other maven based projects work fine.

However, all the projects display errors like the one in the attached image. Also did 'Maven | Update Project...', However no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add maven camel dependencies to pom.xml and try it may work.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.13.1***

Comment: Try not to post link only answers, can you add the content of the link to your answer